# Postgresql fatal the database system is starting up

Tags: postgresql-10

I have a PostgreSQL database which I tried to start in two different machines (same OS version windows 10) without installing. It is started in one machine without issues (immediately started) but facing recovery issue (the database system is starting up) in another machine for more than ten minutes. How do I troubleshoot this issue? Am I missing anything in this?

Comment: Read the logs on the server.

Comment: "fatal the database system is starting up" this is the entry in the logs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql fatal the database system is starting up - windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54922433/postgresql-fatal-the-database-system-is-starting-up-windows-10)